# Parse string into date in rails without view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am converting string into date in my rails application model before saving it into database, how to achieve this using without

> strptime

because strptime purpose is to format and used for views and helpers .

string format:

```
"04-28-2015"(mm-dd-yy)
```

model:

```
def rent_commencement_date=(value)
    self[:rent_commencement_date] = Date.strptime(value, "%m-%d-%Y").to_s(:db)
 end
```

Comment: There is no need for explicit typecasting. Make a database column date column, rails will take care of the rest

Comment: if not typecasting the date value it is not saving into db, need to format to ('yy-mm-dd')

Comment: Try it: just assign a string to a attribute and then read this attribute back - rails automatically converts it into a date for you. Typecasting happens on assignment, not on saving. Unless of course I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used **american_date** gem, it automatically coverts american date format into ISO format. no need to use setter to format the date in model.

```
gem 'american_date'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_date` to convert string into date.

Eg: `"01-01-2015".to_date`

Comment: no , if i have value "04-08-2015", "04-08-2015".to_date returning Tue, 04 Aug 2015 instead  of  Wed, 08 Apr 2015

Comment: "04-28-2015"(mm-dd-yy) this format is wrong try to use dd-mm-yy or yy-mm-dd

Comment: "04-28-2015"(mm-dd-yy), i need this format only, its american date format. any other solution , to convert the american date format to db format

Comment: The following date format won’t be parsed correctly '04/28/2015".to_date ..As per i know strptime is only the solution to convert ...Date.strptime("04/28/2015", '%m/%d/%Y')

Answer (score 0):

use it. i think this is helpful for you

```
date = DateTime.now
puts date.to_date.to_s
```

Or

```
"2011-05-19 10:30:14".to_time
```

Comment: ex: i have string "04-08-2015" with format of ("mm-dd-yy") , if i use "04-08-2015".to_date.to_s its returning 2015-08-04, instead i want the result to be "2015-04-08" ("dd-mm-yy"), using Date.strptime(value, "%m-%d-%Y").to_s(:db) i can get the exact result , but without strptime how to achieve this?